# Adding visibility 0 when class applied to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code which adds header-hide and header-show class to jumbotron

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

/* Jumbotron scroll */

// adjust this number to select when your button appears on scroll-down
var offset = 300,

// bind with the button link
$animation = $('.jumbotron');

// apply animation
$(window).scroll(function(){
( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $animation.addClass('header-hide').removeClass("header-show"):
$animation.addClass('header-show').removeClass("header-hide");
});
});
```

css

```
.header-hide { opacity: 0; }
.header-show { opacity: 1; }
```

I am having difficulty making these changes to my code

1. When the `div` is `opacity: 0` I want it to be `visibility: 0` (I want it to be completely gone when you can't see it, but changing visibility to 0 makes it just blink disappear)

Comment: 1. You need to change the offset variable after it passes the first time, and back again if they scroll up. Use a regular if/else so it doesn't get cluttered. 2. Visibility isn't easily animated, consider applying it at the end using js, or with css keyframes.

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you're wanting -- rather than toggling between classes, I simply set the CSS opacity property for the .jumbotron element. Hope it helps.

EDITED to include the visibility toggle. Basically, when the opacity drops to zero (it actually drops below zero, but when fetched by .css("opacity") it returns as zero), then the visibility is set to hidden. Otherwise, the visibility is set to initial.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  /* Jumbotron scroll */

  // adjust this number to select when your button appears on scroll-down
  var offsetStart = 300,
  offsetEnd = 600,

    // bind with the button link
    $animation = $('.jumbotron');

  // apply animation
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > offsetStart ){
      // we set the opacity level based on percentage through a
      //   given start/end range. By doing this, we can calculate
      //   how quickly we want the fade to happen.
      var currentOpacity = 1-(($(this).scrollTop()-offsetStart) / (offsetEnd-offsetStart) );
      // uncomment this line to watch the numbers fly by.
      //console.log(currentOpacity)
      
      // Now, we want to set the css opacity value for this el.
     $animation.css("opacity", currentOpacity);
     if($animation.css("opacity") == 0) {
       $animation.css("visibility", "hidden");
     } else {
       $animation.css("visibility", "initial");
     }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='jumbotron'>
<p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula.</p>

<p>Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p><p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula.</p>

<p>Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p><p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula.</p>

<p>Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p><p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula.</p>

<p>Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p><p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula.</p>

<p>Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p><p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula.</p>

<p>Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p><p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula.</p>

<p>Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p><p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula.</p>

<p>Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Close, But by doing it this way, The opacity is based on how far they have scrolled. I just want it to fade out when the user scrolls a certain distance down, and fade in when they scroll back up.I removed one of the parameters since I think it has to appear at the same offset from the top whether they scrolled up/down